# Can´t run .class in Terminal if .class was created in an package

Tags: java, cmd, .class-file

I have the problem that i cant run my .class file in the CMD Terminal if i created it inside a package. Outside of the package i didnt have any problems and everything works fine but i wonder why it wont work in the package...
Here is my Code:

```
package Test;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Here is a Picture how it looks in my IDE :

[image: Here is a Picture how it looks in my IDE]

edit:
**I found it out thanks to the comments and some playing around.
The solution is not run it in the Package Folder but in the src folder above with java Test.Test! Thanks for help!**

Comment: How are you trying to run it in terminal `java Test.Test` ?

Comment: Please share your command line and the error you're getting

Comment: To expand upon Sanjeev's comment, when running a Java application, the name is the full name of the class _with the package_. So from the `src` directory, you'll run the application how it is in the comment above.

Comment: `java Test.Test` should work if you run inside working directory. Also avoid having capital case for package name.

Comment: What i do in Terminal is:

   1. Step: type "javac Test.java"

   2. Step: type "java Test"

and then i get this message.

I already tried to run it with "java Test.Test" but same result

Comment: Read the documentation on the `classpath` a.k.a. `cp` option to Java command-line tools. Let's say the package is `foo` relative to target directory `target`, `java -cp target foo.Test` would invoke `Test.main`.

Comment: ok i found the solution :D 
But im a noob with this forum stuff ... how can i post the solution and close the Thread ? xD

Comment: @Joe285 It's a QA site, not a forum. You can't close the question, though you could delete it. Scroll down and look for "Your Answer" and you can input your answer there.